# Standard docker push works but not buildx(docker-container) - ERROR exporting to image

Tags: docker, buildx

I am trying to buildx push to local registry. I have `docker login <registry>` success.

I am building on macos. And it looks like it has something to do with `docker-container`.

standart docker works:

```
docker build -t <registry>/demo
docker push <registry>/demo
```

But buildx do not work:

```
docker buildx create --use --name my-builder --driver-opt network=host --buildkitd-flags '--allow-insecure-entitlement network.host' --use
```

or this:

```
docker buildx create --name my-builder --platform $platforms --driver docker-container --driver-opt network=host --use
```

I get this error:

```
docker buildx build --builder my-builder --tag <registry>:5000/demo -f Dockerfile .

 ...
 => ERROR exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                               0.3s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.2s
 => => exporting manifest sha256:b7bbe730a33ba61b903b4371ded8057dd1a129fd60ff261e3a3ce5ef3425924e                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => => exporting config sha256:c38954cc53caf2cc4dd08ea836c3f2ab8951f400ce6731401628c9ba78f4ce5f                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => => pushing layers                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
------
 > exporting to image:
------
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to do request: Head "https://<registry>:5000/v2/demo/blobs/sha256:659301074bba138f5e7a1896fbe03daa5d95ce5b4f804af5a2c9ea03e9411b8b": http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

is there anything special you have to do to use buildx to push?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using local registry, such as:

**$ docker run -d -p 5001:5000 --restart always --name registry registry:2**

(In my setup , the local registry port is 5001 not 5000 since a mac osx (m1 apply silicon) has a process on that port).

then you probably need to create the custom buildx (bash script), such as:

```
#!/bin/sh
name=container-builder
docker buildx ls | grep -q $name && docker buildx rm $name
docker buildx create --driver-opt network=host --use --config config.toml --name $name
```

and the config.toml file has:

```
[registry."localhost:5001"]
  http = true
```

Also, for my local registry in the Docker Engine (via Dashboard), added to the docker daemon configuation:

```
  "experimental": true,
  "features": {
    "buildkit": true
  },
  "insecure-registries": [
    "localhost:5001"
  ]
```

That should fix the http vs https errors for a local registry.